# Is there a way to get the values of Dynamically created Textbox inside a Dynamically created GridView? Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page used for evaluation. One of the requirements for the page is to create multiple Gridviews to act as the evaluation form. The Gridview is populated by the questions from my database and textbox alongside the questions. So **Column1 = Questions** and **Column2 = Textbox**. The number of Gridviews created depends on the value that the user typed inside a textbox.

My problem is, since it is dynamically created, I don't know how am I suppose to retrieve the values typed in the textbox. I need them to be saved on my database. 
How should I do this? Or is there a better approach to this?

**My Code:**

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSave.Visible = true;
    int parCounter = Convert.ToInt32(participants.Text);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestCS"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "select * from evalForm";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= parCounter; i++)
    {
        GridView objGV = new GridView();
        objGV.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        objGV.ID = "GV"+i;

        for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();                
            boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName.ToString();
            boundfield.HeaderText = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName.ToString();

            objGV.Columns.Add(boundfield);               
        }

        TemplateField tempfield = new TemplateField();
        tempfield.HeaderText = "Score";
        objGV.Columns.Add(tempfield);

        objGV.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(myGrid_RowDataBound);

        compName.Visible = true;
        fromDate.Visible = true;
        toDate.Visible = true;
        participants.Visible = true;

        objGV.DataSource = dt;
        objGV.DataBind();
        Panel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(objGV);
    }        
}

protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
            TextBox txtScore = new TextBox();
            txtScore.ID = "tbScore";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code of the creation I just can give you this hint:
"Use the same name pattern for every element with increasing ID at the end. So you can easíly collecteach field (question/answer) because you 'know' the names. You can loop it in for/while and stop it when there is a `NotFound-Exception`."

Comment: The same way you would a normal textbox inside a GridView, with FindControl. And as @LenglBoy says, giving the dynamic controls an ID that can be used to find it again.

Comment: That's my problem, I updated my question with my code. I don't know how I can find it using FindControl since the Gridview is also dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find any Dynamic controls you have to use FindControl. This also works for GridView controls.

```
//loop the dynamic gridviews
for (i = 1; i <= parCounter; i++)
{
    //use findcontrol and cast back to a gridview
    GridView gv = Panel1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("GV" + i);

    //loop all the rows in the gridview
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        //use findcontrol again to find the textbox
        TextBox tb = row.FindControl("tbScore") as TextBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an error when I am using FindControl for the GridView. It says 'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.UI.Control to System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Comment: I was able to handle the error by adding (GridView) on the line. now the problem is on the foreach loop, it throws a NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Btw, I added your code on an OnClick event which I think is the reason for the error. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Oh I was able to solve my problem now. Just needed to do some modifications on your my code.